# Setting up REST API in Classic ASP

Tags: rest, vbscript, asp-classic

I have the following REST API documentation, i am trying to see if this can be done in Classic ASP.

The destination URL is:

```
https://sandbox.cal-online.co.il/api/PayCalSDK/VerifyAndActivateForPaymentPage
```

```
{ 
    TotalAmount: 1, 
    CurrencyCode: 1,
    TransactionId: GUID, 
    Business: { 
        ApiKey: 'C89371AE-698F-4A15-BD35-2F58377A14F9', // test key 
        Description: ''
    },
    CreditTypes: [ 
        {CreditTypeCode: 1, MaxNumberOfPayments: 1} 
    ] 
}
```

What I have is:

```
Set HTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
HTTP.setOption 2, 13056
HTTP.Open "GET", (url), false
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
HTTP.setRequestHeader "Business.ApiKey", "C89371AE-698F-4A15-BD35-2F58377A14F9"
HTTP.setRequestHeader "transactionId", "397653"
HTTP.setRequestHeader "PayCalSDK.CreditType", "1"
HTTP.setRequestHeader "TotalAmount", "20.20"
HTTP.setRequestHeader "CurrencyCode", "1"
HTTP.setRequestHeader "payCalSdkCharge.ApiUrlPath", "http://www.domain.com"
HTTP.send("")
Response.write HTTP.responseText
Set HTTP = nothing
```

But something is off with the format of the fields, because I am getting an error response from them:

Response is:

```
{"message":"An error has occurred."}
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

*UPDATE:*

I have also tried this code:

```
key = "C89371AE-698F-4A15-BD35-2F58377A14F9"

url = "https://m.cal-online.co.il/api/PayCalSDK/VerifyAndActivateForPaymentPage?"
str = "{ TotalAmount: 1, CurrencyCode: 1, TransactionId: 36985223, Business: { ApiKey: '" & key & "',Description: '' }, CreditTypes: [ {CreditTypeCode: 1, MaxNumberOfPayments: 1}] }"

Dim oXMLHttp
Set oXMLHttp=Server.Createobject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
oXMLHttp.open "post", url & str,false

oXMLHttp.send
response.write oXMLHttp.responseText
Set oXMLHttp = Nothing
```

And i get the same response:

```
{"message":"An error has occurred."}
```

Comment: Don't you think that showing the error response might be a good idea? How are we supposed to help if we don't know what the error response is?

Comment: @Lankymart - good point. I hadnt include the response, because its pretty clear to me that its because of the formatting. I have edited the question accordingly, thanks

Comment: Where are you creating the json shown in the question? Do you have a link to the documentation (in English) ?

Comment: in terms of an API that is a terrible error response, it tells you absolutely nothing!

Comment: Maybe you should be posting as JSON? Does that API have any documentation?

Comment: What makes you think that the stuff you are sending is supposed to be represented by HTTP Request Headers?

Comment: If the first example is from the *"API documentation"* and it is JSON, then why are you not sending the request with a `JSON` body? You should probably be sending via the `POST` method as well? Ideally we need to see the API Documentation to confirm this for sure.

Comment: Thank you all, I will try see what i can dig up the docs and get back to you.

Comment: Question updated with json post syntax, thanks

Comment: Your latest example is closer, but because its a `POST` will need to pass the request body with the `Send()` method not as part of the URL on the `Open()` method.

Comment: I hope that `key` you've posted in the example isn't a real one?

Comment: @Lankymart thank you. 1) correct, demo key. 2) I didnt understand the fix: you say remove the `open` and use only `send`?

Comment: No, take `str` out of the `Open()` *(you still need the method to configure the URL you are sending to)* and add it to the `Send()` so something like `oXMlHttp.Send str`. This is because `POST` requests send their data in the body of the request not as a querystring on a URL, that is only for `GET` requests.

Comment: Strange sort of JSON in that example as well.  Usually the parameter names have double quotes around them (as the error response has it) and string values also have double quotes rather than single.

Comment: And yes, Classic ASP can do REST & JSON although I used a ASP JSON http://www.aspjson.com class to easily create and parse (although seems unavailable at this time, here is what it used to look like https://web.archive.org/web/20160505062206/http://www.aspjson.com/)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf it's still valid JSON you don't have to wrap JSON object property names in double quotes. Works both ways and most JSON parsers should be fine with either style.

Comment: Thanks Guys, i think are on the right track. Using the code above, the message is now: `{"message":{"name":"RequestNotValid","value":2,"text":"שדה קלט אינו תקין","severity":"W"},"response":true,"tag":null}`, which i understand means something wrong about one of the values i am sending, so i guess the communication is working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C/O [Lankymart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/692942/lankymart)'s assistance via comments, try this

```
key = "C89371AE-698F-4A15-BD35-2F58377A14F9"

url = "https://m.cal-online.co.il/api/PayCalSDK/VerifyAndActivateForPaymentPage?"
str = "{ TotalAmount: 1, CurrencyCode: 1, TransactionId: 36985223, Business: { ApiKey: '" & key & "',Description: '' }, CreditTypes: [ {CreditTypeCode: 1, MaxNumberOfPayments: 1}] }"

Dim oXMLHttp
Set oXMLHttp=Server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
oXMLHttp.open "POST", url,false
oXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
oXMLHttp.send str
response.write oXMLHttp.responseText
Set oXMLHttp = Nothing
```